# Differential Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm using an LM358 as a differential amplifier to measure the voltage drop across a resistor.
I'm connecting an electronic active load to the J1 and J2 terminals to emulate a load.

[image]

The output of the LM358 should be about 2.55V when the load draws 1A. Vo = Vi x (Rf / Ri).

When I simulate the circuit it works fine, but in practice, the output does not vary when I vary the load and it remains at about 10.6V, even when the load is set to draw 1A.

Are my differential input voltages to close to the rail or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 10.6 volts would be a positive saturation value, so you have a miss-wire somewhere.

Comment: Input voltage of OPAMP (+ & - inputs) must be lower than (Vcc-2v). Otherwise it won't operate as expected. Refer to the LM358 datasheet for more info.

Comment: By the way, it's not a precise circuit to measure the little voltage across sampling resistors (0.68ohm). The errors in values of 1K & 15K resistors would dominate that little voltage!

Comment: Yes too close to the rail.  Some popular hobbyist rail-rail op amps are: LMC6482, OP777, TLC2272 LM6142, OPA2140

Comment: @wbeaty, curious, what makes them "hobbyist"? Put otherwise, why lump them together in this particular sub-set?

Comment: @P2000 For most reasons "Hobbyist" means low cost. Op-amps can be a $1 each, or $20 each for high-performance normally not needed. High accuracy resistors (0.1%) would add to the expense.

Comment: In consumer electronics, cost is a major concern also. In some ways designing high volume consumer electronics is the opposite of hobbyist. And yet, there too, low-cost is extremely important. To me "hobbyist" implies easy to use but not practical for real designs. The LM317, the 555 timer. That kind of thing.

Comment: Have to agree, I do not believe there is such a thing as a "hobbyist" electronic part. Even the LM317 and 555, although not always desirable, but when suitable, have their place in production electronics. Low cost.

Comment: Hobbyist = oolllllld!  And none of this soic-only nonsense!  We start using uA741, then refuse to jump on this Newfangled TL071 bandwagon to which all the whippersnappers are "hep."  (Hmm, wasn't LM324 the very first, but only for negative rail?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase values of R6 and R12 to 3K or so to get op-amp into its common-mode range, then it should work fine within its limits. C4 should be 100uF for current stability. Per comments above consider using a rail-to-rail op-amp.

Also consider using a negative power rail, that is a bi-polar power supply of +/- 12 volts or more. This greatly increases the dynamic tracking range of your circuit.

For best accuracy pick a better op-amp than an ancient LM358. Hand-pick R6 and R12 to match within 0.1% if possible. Do the same for R13 and R14. With the values you have, slight miss-matches in resistor values get amplified 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the datasheet and did a couple of measurements again. The differential input voltage is too small and too close to the negative rail.

When I increase the voltage drop across the shunt to the region of 100mV and higher, I get a valid reading.

I do not think a negative supply on the negative rail will solve the problem when using an LM358 (not my first choice either). I'll just have to select a more suitable op-amp or revise the design.

Thanks for all your inputs